# why does kafka docker need to listen on unix socket

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am using docker image for kafka from [wurstmeister](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker)
The docker-compose file defines a volume such as `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

What is the purpose of the above unix socket?

When should a docker image declare the above volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [kafka-docker](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) project is making (questionable, see below) use of the `docker` command run *inside* the `kafka` container in order to introspect your docker environment.  For example, it will determine the advertised kafka port like this:

```
export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=$(docker port `hostname` $KAFKA_PORT | sed -r "s/.*:(.*)/\1/g")
```

There is a `broker-list.sh` script that looks for kafka brokers like this:

```
CONTAINERS=$(docker ps | grep 9092 | awk '{print $1}')
```

In order to run the `docker` cli inside the container, it needs access to the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket on your host.

Okay, that's it for the facts.  The following is just my personal opinion:

I think this is frankly a terrible idea and that the only containers that should ever have access to the docker socket are those that are explicitly managing containers.  There are other mechanisms available for performing container configuration and discovery that do not involve giving the container root access to your host, which is exactly what you are doing when you give something access to the docker socket.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Docker daemon listens on unix:///var/run/docker.sock to allow only local connections by the root user. So, generally speaking, if we can access to this socket from somewhere else, we can talk to the Docker daemon or extract information about other containers.

If we want some processes inside our container to access to information of other containers managed by the Docker daemon (run on our host), we can declare the volume like above.
Let's see an example from the wurstmeister docker.

1. The [Docker file](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile):

At the end of the file, it will call:

```
 CMD ["start-kafka.sh"]
```

2. [start-kafka.sh](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/start-kafka.sh)

Let's take a look from the line 6:

```
if [[ -z "$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT" ]]; then
    export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=$(docker port `hostname` $KAFKA_PORT | sed -r "s/.*:(.*)/\1/g")
fi
```

When start his Kafka container, he wants to execute below command inside the Kafka container (to find the port mapping to container...):

```
docker port `hostname` $KAFKA_PORT
```

Note that he did mount the above volume to be able to execute command like this.

Reference from [Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/quickstart/)(search for the Socket keyword)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of the above unix socket?

Mounting the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket in a container provides access to the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) hosted by the docker daemon. Anyone with access to this socket has complete control of docker and the host running docker (essentially root access).

> When should a docker image declare the above volume?

Very rarely. If you are running a docker admin tool that requires API access inside a container then it needs to be mounted (or accessible [via TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758886/1318694)) so the tool can manage the hosting docker daemon.

As [larsks mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38649896/1318694), docker-kafka's use of the socket for config discovery is very questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to mount docker.sock file and can be avoided by commenting out appropriate lines in kafka-docker/Dockerfile & start-kafka.sh. No need to add broker-list.sh to kafka container.