# docker build step plugin inside jenkins docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker

We are running jenkins in a docker container and we want to use the docker build step plugin. The documentation tells us:
You have to make sure that Docker service is running on slaves where you run the build. In Jenkins global configuration, you need to specify Docker REST API URL (typically somethig like `http://127.0.0.1:2375`)

But I see very often that people are using `0.0.0.0:2375`

What is the difference and which do we have to use when we just want to use the docker daemon inside one docker container on one server (docker daemon is running on the same server)?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the differences between 0.0.0.0:2375 and 127.0.0.1:2375, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045872/6606196) it's basically whether you want to open the host up to the outside or not.

If it's all on one server, I'm assuming both should work as it's all on the same host..

Comment: but when I expose to 127.0.0.1. Will I be able to use this REST API in a docker container on the same host? (because the container has its own IP)